# Can't parse from Json to Object Array in Unity (Firebase)

Tags: c#, json, firebase, unity-game-engine

Good afternoon, I spent the whole morning breaking my head trying to pass a JSON to an array using the JsonHelper class, without success. Let's see if someone throws a cable to see where the failure is. Clarify that I'm making a game in Unity (in case Unity is the one that limits the code or something).

The fact is that I'm trying to make a ranking with the players and scores I have in a database in Firebase.

As you can see below with the class WWW sent the route and the text that returns the www is that json below.

```
public void Ranking ()
{
    string url = "https://example.firebaseio.com/.json";
    WWW www = new WWW (url);
    StartCoroutine (WaitForRequest (www));
}

IEnumerator WaitForRequest (WWW www)
{
    yield return www;

    // check for errors
    if (www.error == null)
    {
        User[] users;
        users = JsonHelper.FromJson <User> (www.text);

        Debug.Log ("WWW Ok !:" + www.text);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log ("WWW Error:" + www.error);
    }
}
```

And this is the returned string

```
{"Eduardito": {"playerName": "Eduardito", "playerScore": "4"}, "Joel": {"playerName": "Joel", "playerScore": "4"}, "Karla": { "playerName": "Karla", "playerScore": "5"}, "Miguelin": {"playerName": "Miguelin", "playerScore": "4"}}
```

So far so good, the mess arrives at the time of using the JsonHelper class to pass it to an array. All the time it returns `null`. I do not know if it's because in the User's class something is wrong or not. Anyone who can think of something? Thanksss! Sorry for my bad english

Edit: The user class simply has the constructor and the two variables for the name and the score, nothing more.

I'm putting the JsonHelper class in

```
public static class JsonHelper
{
    public static User[] FromJson<User>(string json)
    {
        Wrapper<User> wrapper = JsonUtility.FromJson<Wrapper<User>>(json);

        Debug.Log(wrapper.Items);

        return wrapper.Items;
    }

    public static string ToJson<User> (User[] array)
    {
        Wrapper<User> wrapper = new Wrapper<User> ();
        wrapper.Items = array;
        return JsonUtility.ToJson(wrapper);
    }

    public static string ToJson <User>(User[] array, bool prettyPrint)
    {
        Wrapper <User> wrapper = new Wrapper<User>();
        wrapper.Items = array;
        return JsonUtility.ToJson(wrapper, prettyPrint);
    }

    internal static string ArrayToJsonString<T>(User[] res, bool v)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    [Serializable]
    private class Wrapper<User>
    {
        public User[] Items;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using Firebase's Unity Plugin instead of the API?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, lets start from the beginning. The JSON returning from your WWW request is not an array, its an object. So you should try to change the format of the return of your request to something like:

```
[{"playerName": "Eduardito", "playerScore": "4"}, {"playerName": "Joel", "playerScore": "4"}]
```

Now this is an array!

Then, you should be sure that your User class is marked as serializable too, don't forget that!

At last but not least, remember that the JsonUtility class only works with objects, so it will not be able to deserialize the array because an array is not exactly an object. So, since your Wrapper class contains an parameter called **Items**, the JSONUtility will look for a parameter called **Items** on the given JSON.
You can fix this by changing your JSONHelper.FromJson function to something like:

```
Wrapper <User> wrapper = JsonUtility.FromJson <Wrapper <User >> ("{\"Items\":" + json + "}");
```

That way the JsonUtility deserializer will find an parameter called Items and will correctly deserialize it to your wrapper class.

Here is a simple version of your code so you can better understand what Im talking. You can copy and past it in your unity and it should works properly.

```
public class JSONTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    private string jsonStr = "[{\"playerName\": \"Eduardito\", \"playerScore\": \"4\"}, {\"playerName\": \"Joel\", \"playerScore\": \"4\"}]";

    [Serializable]
    public class JSONArray<T>
    {
        public T[] Items;
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class User
    {
        public string playerName;
        public string playerScore;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        JSONArray<User> users = JsonUtility.FromJson<JSONArray<User>>("{\"Items\":" + jsonStr + "}");
        if (users.Items != null && users.Items.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (User user in users.Items)
            {
                Debug.Log("Deserialized user " + user.playerName);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("I should never reach this code.");
        }
    }
}
```